# I cloned a HDD with ddrescue. What next?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, disk-cloning, ddrescue

The original drive would not pass chkdsk or a clone using Macrium Reflect or EaseUS.

I read up about ddrescue and decided to give it a shot. This is after all just a hard drive I used for installing games and media. All of it was already backed up a few days before the failure. I used SystemRescue and after 14 days the clone of my 3TB HDD on to a 4TB HDD has completed with a recovery of 99.99%.

I used "ddrescue -f -n /dev/sda /dev/sdb /root/recovery.log"

Before I move this hard drive out of my backup rig and back into the main PC is there anything else I should do to verify my clone has the best possible results? I am just dipping my feet into Linux so I'll be using this as a learning experience as well.

Comment: well, DD rescue is usually used to create an image on solid media from which you will run further recovery operations, to attempt to restore the data to another disk. start with partition based recovery utilities like Testdisk (most OSes), Recuva (Windows), easus (Windows), etc. These tools will attempt to restore a partition and its filesystem. if a partition and filesystem can't be recovered, then you fall back to filecarving utilities like PhotoRec (multi-os) or either of the windows apps above, to scan the disk for known file headers and footers. name and location are lost in that case.

Answer (score 0):

> Before I move this hard drive out of my backup rig and back into the main PC is there anything else I should do to verify my clone has the best possible results?

You can only verify against the source, but I would assume the copy process to run error-free.

> I am just dipping my feet into Linux so I'll be using this as a learning experience as well.

I would duplicate your target again into a second copy. Judged by the time it took for your first duplicate your source drive has health issues. The second duplicate will be generated in a timespan of hours instead of days. You can then use the second copies for experiments. You could go on with your first duplicate and log file and rerun ddrescue, hoping to recover even more sectors.

Operating on your second duplicate has the advantage of ruling out hardware-related problems so that the recovery software you are testing will not be negatively affected by read errors.

Please continue to read the comment of Frank Thomas, that I consider as a qualified answer instead of just being a comment.